# Get selected item on select with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, select

Look, i'm getting crazy, i can't get the selected item inside a normal select dropdown list (The values of the list are created dynamiclly with js).

I have a list of items and that are the columns of a table and i want when i click on an item, the column is added to the table and if i click another time in that item the column is removed.

I've tried to use a change event with jquery and onchange event with js but if i select the item two times in a row the column is added but not removed because the value hasn't changed.
I've tried to give a onclick event to the options of the select but nothing happens when i click on one. I've tried to capturo the clicked option from the select with jquery with this code:

```
$("#selectTableLt").on("click", "option", function() {
let clickedOption = $(this);
console.log(clickedOption);
});
```

But nothing happens.

Can anyone help me with this, please? Thank you

Edit:

My html:

```
<select name="leftColumns" id="selectTableLt"></select>
```

I load the options with javascript but they look like:

```
<option value="opt1">Option 1</option>
```

It's very simple

Comment: I think it would help to see your HTML markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a solution to handle the multiple click events and fetch the dropdown selected value

```js
var oldValue = null;
$(document).on("click","#selectTableLt", function(){
  s = $(this);
  val = s.val();
  if (oldValue == null) {
      oldValue = val;
  } else {
      var newValue = s.val();
      if (newValue != "") {
       var finalVal  = oldValue == s.val() ?  oldValue : newValue;
       console.log(finalVal)
      }

      $(document).unbind('click.valueCheck');
      oldValue = null;      
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectTableLt">
    <option value="0">One</option>
    <option value="1">Two</option>
</select>
```

You need to fetch the value using $.val() function

bind event to document in order to handle the dynamic event listener

```
$(document).on( eventName, selector, function(){} );
```

Using the Change Event:

```js
    $(document).on("change","#selectTableLt", function() {
 let clickedOption = $(this).val();
 console.log(clickedOption);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectTableLt">
    <option value="0">One</option>
    <option value="1">Two</option>
</select>
```

Using the Click Event:

```js
$(document).on("click","#selectTableLt", function() {
 let clickedOption = $(this).val();
 console.log(clickedOption);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectTableLt">
    <option value="0">One</option>
    <option value="1">Two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. I changed it and i even put a breakpoint in the dev tools of chrome and click on the options of the select and it doesn't stop there. It isn't getting the event

Comment: Try updated code by me, i have bind to change event now

Comment: Now it works but  if i click option 1, it logs in the console "Option 1", but if i click another time option 1 it doesn't do anything, because the value hasn't changed, but i need to capture that second click in the same option

Comment: we have use change event replace change with click then it will work,. Ihave added code for same in answer

Comment: If i replace the change for the click, when i just click on the select to deploy the list, it logs me another time the value, and if you click the list, click out, click the list, click out many times it logs all the times the value, and i need to log it two times, to add it to the table and to delete it, but thanks for the help!

Comment: That's why we should always prefer and use change event with select box, cause the click event will trigger on an simple mouse click too

Comment: I prefer change too, but with change event if you click an option and then you click another time the same option, it doesn't trigger because it hasn't changed

Comment: Check my latest solution for handling the multiple click issue and show value on selection only once

Comment: WOW! It works perfectly! You are increible! hahaha thank you very much! I was getting cazy! hahahah

Comment: I edited a little bit your code because if you click the select to deploy it but then you click outside, when you click another time the select and select an option nothing happens, and when you click another time to deploy the list it logs the option you selected before, just encapsule the lines below "let newValue = s.val();" in a "if (newValue != "") {...} and now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

**Check this out**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Select from  dropdown list</title>
 </head>

 <body>

  <h1>Select from  dropdown list</h1>

  <p id="result">Result here</p>
  
  <select id="country">
   <option value="None">-- Select --</option>
   <option value="ID1">America</option>
   <option value="ID2" selected>India </option>
   <option value="ID3">England</option>
  </select>

  <script>

   function GetSelectedValue(){
    var e = document.getElementById("country");
    var result = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
   }

   function GetSelectedText(){
    var e = document.getElementById("country");
    var result = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
   }
   
  </script>

  <br/>
  <br/>
  <button type="button" onclick="GetSelectedValue()">Get Selected Value</button>

  <button type="button" onclick="GetSelectedText()">Get Selected Text</button>
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi @Avinash,  alexmaza_wd  wants to use the click event instead

Comment: Hi, it happens the same, it logs the result always, even when i just click the select to deploy the list, because i can't do it with an external button, i have to do it with the select, but thanks!